# perform a hotkey when press a graphical button

Tags: c#, user-interface

I got a thought experiment with a graphical user interface for writing a command.
There are buttons for saving, writing cursive and so on.....
Now when i press the button save, i want to that the compiler perform Ctrl+S like in every textdocument, or change the marked one to cursive with Ctrl+Shift+K.

I tried to set the variable to the value of the ascii code, but this ain´t worked. Now i need help that the compiler perform the hotkey.
Is there a function in C# or is there another way to realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually those hotkeys are implemented functions of the programs you use (e.g. word). The hotkey just executes the same function as the button you can press - the compiler doesn't know the hotkey Ctrl+Shift+K.

Just think about it: If the compiler knew about those hotkeys, it would have to know how to make the selected text in the focused textbox cursive - wouldn't this be kind of strange?

I might misunderstand your question, maybe you just wanted to ask how to type text with a simulated keyboard for the form, because you already implemented the shortcut functionability. In that case you'd have two options:

1. Call the function called when you press the specified shortcut
2. Actually simulate keypresses to the form

The second one is done like that:

```
SendKeys.Send("^S"); //For Ctrl+S - ^ is the Control button
```

For other special keys with the SendKeys function take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx.